# telerik grid gives "Unexpected token <" error when is empty and configured for client operation mode

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a simple view with a telerik grid, no javascript file on it. this is my grid:

```
  @{Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("myGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(m => m.myColumn);
    })
    .DataBinding(data => data.Ajax().OperationMode(GridOperationMode.Client))
    .Sortable(sort => sort.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn))
    .Scrollable(c=>c.Height("300px"))
    .Pageable(paging => { paging.Enabled(true); paging.PageSize(10); })
    .Render();
    }
```

when the grid is empty, this error message is displayed in the console:
[image]

If I remove the dataBinding line, the error goes away, but I need the grid to be configured for client operations.
Any ideas how to fix this error message?

Comment: That looks like a javascript syntax error.  Are you displaying data that is screwing up the html?

Comment: This error is displayed only when the grid is empty, so there is no data to screw up the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround. I added this method on data binding event of the grid, which prevents any requests if the grid is empty.

```
<script>
function onDataBinding(e) {
    if ($("#myGrid").data("tGrid").data.length == 0)
        e.preventDefault();
};
```